# What was the first science fiction TV show?

Tags: tv, history-of, science-fiction-genre

Is the BBC's pre-war live adaptation of Karel Capek's *R.U.R.,* broadcast on February 11, 1938, the first science fiction television show? Originally, I would have thought that the American series *Captain Video* starting in 1949 was the first, and it may have been the first series.

But in doing my research before asking the question, I came up with the BBC broadcast. It was a 35 minute extract from the novel. It's so early that I'm tempted to call it the first, but there might be something even older.

[image: R.U.R. screenshot showing a scientist and 3 "robots"]

Comment: TV shows only (so not movies?)

Comment: @MacCooper No, just TV shows/broadcasts. I think the first movie must be "Le Voyage dans la Lune," from 1902 but that's probably worth another question if it hasn't been asked and answered before.

Comment: Ah righto. Good thing too because my potential answer was three decades later than Le Voyage anyway!

Comment: I think the left- and rightmost robots in the photo look something like Data from TNG.

Comment: *R.U.R.* is a play, not a novel.

Comment: If this version of R.U.R. was broadcast on a single day, February 11, 1938, and was only 35 minutes long it counts as a single episode  program and not as a series of episodes. Therefore it might count as the first science fiction television program but not as the first science fiction television series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hard to say with certainty but a number of reputable-seeming sources do say it was the first, for example [p. 77 of *Popular Television Drama: Critical Perspectives*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PYYty2bXa1UC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA77&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) says:

> The first television science-fiction programme was the B.B.C.'s adaptation of R.U.R.

And [p. 308 of *Guinness World Records 2011*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GJ-Lts1QgrkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA308&redir_esc=y) says:

> 1938: First TV sci-fi aired—an adaptation of R.U.R..

Comment: I think you must be right, but I'm going to leave it open for a little while to see if anyone finds something earlier.